# Calculation for a lower bound for the amount of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

I know there are several bounds for $\pi(x)$, which is the prime counting function.
But for my thesis I want to calculate a very rough estimation.
I'd appreciate any feedback on my calculation.
So I have the proth number $n = h\cdot2^{k}+1$ where $h<2^k$.
I want to know how many primes (again: Very roughly) I had to check if I did trial division.
So I need a lower bound for the amount of primes up to $\sqrt{n}$. I use the formula

$$
\pi(x) \geq \frac{x}{\log(x)-1}.
$$

I have

$$
\frac{\sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1}}{\log(\sqrt{h\cdot 2^k+1)}-1}
\geq
\frac{\sqrt{h\cdot 2^k}}{\frac{1}{2}\log(h\cdot 2^k+1)}
=
\frac{2\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^\frac{k}{2}}{\log(h\cdot 2^k+1)}
=
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{\log(h\cdot 2^k+1)}
>
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{\log(h\cdot 2^{k+1})}
$$
Now I use $h<2^k$:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{\log(h\cdot 2^{k+1})}
>
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{\log(2^{2k+1})}
>
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{\log(2^{2k+2})}
=
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{(k+1)\log(4)}
>
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}{(k+1)\cdot 2}
=
\frac{\sqrt{h}\cdot 2^{\frac{k}{2}}}{(k+1)}
$$

So for $h = 2^{5001} + 5473$ and $k=10.000$ I receive
$$
\pi(x) > 2^{7486} \geq 10^{2253}.
$$

Comment: A lower bound is simply $\pi(h)$ and this caanot be made significantly better for large $h$. Your final result is much bigger than $h$ , how did you arrive there ?

Comment: @Peter Sorry. I wanted to calculate $\pi(\sqrt{n})\geq...$ for the $h$ and for $k = 10^4$. I will edit it in the question.